# separating C++ class into header and cpp files

Tags: c++, class

so its my first try in separating my class... but i'm having some trouble with it.

here is the .h file

```
#ifndef COURSE_H
#define COURSE3_H
class course3
{
string coursename;
int courseid;
int passinggrade;
int numcredits;
public:
course3( string acoursename, int acourseid, int apassinggrade,int anumcredits );
string getcoursename();
int getcouseid();
int getpassinggrade();
int getnumcredits();
};
```

and here is the cpp...

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <course3.h>
using namespace std;
 course3::course3( string acoursename, int acourseid, int apassinggrade,int anumcredits ) //constructors
{
    coursename=acoursename;
    courseid=acourseid;
    passinggrade=apassinggrade;
    numcredits=anumcredits;
}
string course3::getcoursename()
{
    return coursename;
}
int course3::getcourseid()
{
    return courseid;
}
int course3::getpassinggrade()
{
    return passinggrade;
}
int course3::getnumcredits()
{
    return numcredits;
}

 }
```

am i doing anything wrong ?

errors:

> error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'coursename'
>
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

and so much more, but close to these

Comment: *Where* do you get the errors? In which files? On which lines?

Comment: okay so i moved the string and using namespace std to the h file and things got better....
 still 2 errors

Error 1 fatal error C1070: mismatched #if/#endif pair in file 'c:\users\ridahel\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\class course new copy\class course new copy\course3.h' c:\users\ridahel\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\class course new copy\class course new copy\course3.h 18
both on line 18

Comment: 1) #define does not match #ifndef

Comment: 2) `string` is not defined in header file

Comment: Such a formidable pile of defects indicates that you should perhaps reduce the amount of code that you write before you try to compile it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your header guard in the .h file is declared wrong, and you are missing an `#endif` for it.

`#include <string>` belongs in the .h file, since you are using `std::string` in the `.h` file.

If you want to use `string` instead of `std::string` in the `.h` file, the `using` statement needs to be in the `.h` file as well.  But you should learn to avoid `using namespace std;` as it dumps the entire `std` namespace into the global namespace.  While it does work, it is not optimal or desirable.  If you don't want to specify `std::` everywhere that `std::string` is used, then you can at least limit the scope of the `using` statement via `using std::string;` instead.

You have an extra `}` at the end of the .cpp file that does not belong there.

Try this:

```
#ifndef COURSE3_H
#define COURSE3_H

#include <string>

class course3
{
    std::string coursename;
    int courseid;
    int passinggrade;
    int numcredits;
public:
    course3( std::string acoursename, int acourseid, int apassinggrade, int anumcredits );
    std::string getcoursename();
    int getcourseid();
    int getpassinggrade();
    int getnumcredits();
};

#endif
```

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "course3.h"

course3::course3( std::string acoursename, int acourseid, int apassinggrade, int anumcredits ) //constructors
{
    coursename = acoursename;
    courseid = acourseid;
    passinggrade = apassinggrade;
    numcredits = anumcredits;
}

std::string course3::getcoursename()
{
    return coursename;
}

int course3::getcourseid()
{
    return courseid;
}

int course3::getpassinggrade()
{
    return passinggrade;
}

int course3::getnumcredits()
{
    return numcredits;
}
```

Or:

```
#ifndef COURSE3_H
#define COURSE3_H

#include <string>
using std::string;

class course3
{
    string coursename;
    int courseid;
    int passinggrade;
    int numcredits;
public:
    course3( string acoursename, int acourseid, int apassinggrade, int anumcredits );
    string getcoursename();
    int getcourseid();
    int getpassinggrade();
    int getnumcredits();
};

#endif
```

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "course3.h"

course3::course3( string acoursename, int acourseid, int apassinggrade, int anumcredits ) //constructors
{
    coursename = acoursename;
    courseid = acourseid;
    passinggrade = apassinggrade;
    numcredits = anumcredits;
}

string course3::getcoursename()
{
    return coursename;
}

int course3::getcourseid()
{
    return courseid;
}

int course3::getpassinggrade()
{
    return passinggrade;
}

int course3::getnumcredits()
{
    return numcredits;
}
```

Comment: There are various opinions on whether to use `using namespace` in a source-file (cpp), and I'm not necessarily disagreeing with you on that, but please remove the sentence saying "using namespace std belongs in the .h file". This is the main reason why people object to use `using namespace` in global scope in the first place.

Comment: @Excelcius: If Rida wants to use `string` instead of `std::string` in the `.h` file, a `using` statement is needed in the `.h` file.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes of course, but writing `using namespace` in global scope in a header is considered bad practice and since you advise against it in source files I suspected you don't want to see it in the header as well. I think it's better for beginners to learn what's best not what makes their code work, that's why I mentioned it. The current edit is better, `using std::string` in header-files is somewhat debatable as well, but bringing one symbol into scope is already much better than the whole std-namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Use `#include "course3.h"` instead of `#include <course3.h>`.
Using double quotes, the preprocessor will look for the header in your local directory. With the brackets, it will search for the header in the system headers.

Then there is a typo in your inclusion guards. I advise you to use `#pragma once` if you do not want to write `#ifndef...` and so on, and take the risk to make a mistake (check first if the compiler you use supports it. VS, GCC since 3.4, Clang and more do).

Comment: The usual warnings with `#pragma once`: Not a standard feature so do not expect compiler support. Do expect complete silence and weird error messages when it is not supported. Do not use with a complex build hierarchy using network shares and symlinks. Should not be an issue with a school assignment (simple build environment) using MSVC (supports `once`), but watch out if the marker compiles and evaluates the code with a compiler that does not support `once`.

Comment: You are right. But the OP being a beginner and using Visual Studio, `#pragma once` could be very useful and intuitive.

Comment: Agree, but make sure the person doing the marking uses a compiler supporting the extension.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided above is correct but there is a typo in the name of the function `getcourseid` declaration, and function implementation